# Converting analog CRT adjustments to digital

Tags: potentiometer, digital-potentiometer

Many CRTs use analog controls (potentiometers) to adjust various picture settings such as brightness, contrast, geometry, etc. My objective is to replace these analog controls with digital ones.

---

### Preface

I only know the basics of CRTs. I have some experience with programming microcontrolers like the Arduino and Raspberry Pi, but little EE experience. I know CRTs are dangerous and I will only be messing with the detached control board.

I am working on building an arcade cabinet that can play multiple games (MAME). Many games run at various resolutions including CGA, EGA, and VGA. In order to run these games at their original/native resolutions, a CRT that supports 15kHz, 24kHz and 31kHz horizontal frequencies is needed. These are called multisync/tri-sync/tri-mode monitors. 10 years ago there were digial multisync CRTs available, but now only analog multisyncs are available. Specifically, [this Makvision M3129DS-LG CRT](https://na.suzohapp.com/products/monitors/49-2715-00).

The difference is important as picture adjustments are necessary when switching between horizontal frequencies. A digital multisync stores adjustments for each frequency and automatically switches between them. An analog requires manual adjustment after each switch. I want to avoid having to manually adjust the picture when switching between games.

---

My solution is to convert the analog adjustments to digital ones using a microcontroller. I would simply replace the mechanical potentiometers on the control board with digital potentiometers controlled by a microcontroller. However, after doing some reading on digital potentiometers (digipots) vs normal/mechanical potentiometers (pots), I have come up with this list of considerations:

1. **Noise**: Do digipots produce enough noise that it would affect the picture? I would assume not.
2. **Zero crossing**: This was frequently mentioned regarding preventing popping noises in audio when using digipots as a gain/volume control. Do I need to worry about this? You can get digipots with zero-crossing detectors built in.
3. **Maximum operating frequency**: Does this refer to the frequency of the signal the digipot is providing resistance on? Do I need to worry about this?
4. **Power-up/default resistance value and off-state resistance value**: If the monitor receives power before the digipot receives power or before the digipot is set, the resistance provided by the digipot is undefined and could be at the ends of the resistance range (turned all the way up/down). You can get nonvolatile digipots that retain their resistance value without power and on power up.

My biggest question is: **How at risk is the CRT while I play around with this?** Again, I will only be messing with the detached control board. Does the monitor have safe guards in place to prevent damage? For example, what if you were to turn the existing pots all the way up or down? What if the existing pots were removed (infinite resistance) or shorted (0 resistance)? I assume I can use resistors in series and in parallel to ensure the resistance is always in a "safe" range. I don't want to fry an expensive CRT.

I have not purchased the CRT yet. I want to know if this is a feasible idea or not.

Comment: Why not just digitize the video output using a video decoder chip and then display it on an LCD?  Unless you are going for the authenticity / Retro look of the CRT, that would probably have more chance of success.

Comment: Won’t help you in this case unless you go to extreme lengths but Barco made custom ASICs for the very purpose in CRT projectors. I2C in and analog pot out for convergence and picture tuning.

Comment: Authenticity is the objective. Having seen both, even on a 2K LCD with HLSL shaders to mimic a CRT, CRTs look way better and much more authentic (in my opinion).

Comment: I had a 21" Hitachi CRT with 200MHz bandwidth for high pixel rates that supported much more that went into the garbage.  I'm sure there are many others around. The Makvision is only 65MHz

Comment: Given that the max resolution is 640x480 and vertical refresh is 70Hz, my calculations tell me only 32.3MHz of bandwidth is needed. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Nope ancient retro games were slow video... but over 10 yrs ago I was using it for Windows ...WOuldn't be easier to buy a used NEC 4D CRT?

Comment: Kodi can support an addon that emulates every retro game on Windows

Comment: If you can find any used digital multisync CRT for sale, let me know. I have been unable to. Closest is a Wells Gardner D9200 on ebay but it has a similar problem of requiring a jumper cable to be moved when switching from VGA to CGA/EGA. Further, 16" is quite small for an arcade machine.